# Why doesn't the shared pointer aliasing constructor use pass-by-value semantics

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

The shared pointer aliasing constructor (8 on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)) takes `r` by a constant reference. Is there a reason that value semantics are avoided?

The libcxx [implementation of this](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/681cde7dd8b5613dbafc9ca54e0288477f946be3/libcxx/include/__memory/shared_ptr.h#L581-L589) basically copies the two pointers and increments the reference count if applicable.

```
    shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<_Yp>& __r, element_type *__p) _NOEXCEPT
        : __ptr_(__p),
          __cntrl_(__r.__cntrl_)
    {
        if (__cntrl_)
            __cntrl_->__add_shared();
    }
```

Is there a reason we cannot rely on the copy constructor to increment the reference count? So something like the following:

```
    template<class _Yp>
    shared_ptr(shared_ptr<_Yp> __r, element_type *__p) _NOEXCEPT
        : __ptr_(__p),
          __cntrl_(__r.__cntrl_) {}
```

This was, the caller can avoid the atomic reference increment with `std::move`. I see c++20 adds an r-value overload that I assume is for this purpose. But why was this chosen over switching to the simpler value semantics and having only one overload.

Comment: Is the “does” in the question title meant to be “doesn’t”?

Comment: In the pass-by-value case, when `__r` is destroyed it will decrease the reference count again. So has a different effect.

Comment: Haven't thought this through completely, but I've got the feeling that removing an overload could possibly result in issues in the compatibility with older versions of the class...

Comment: Cppreference lists both a copy and a move constructor for #8. You are looking at the copy constructor.

Comment: @BoP That is an issue with the proposed implementation only. A correct one would put `__r` in a moved-out state before letting it be destroyed. That would give it the right semantics.

Comment: Using pass by value for costly copy objects (f.ex. large containers) is a good pattern but then you forgot the second part of pattern, to steal the copy of the local variable (f.ex. steal the internal rep of a container and reset the local variable). That way the dtor of the local is a NOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the destructor. your suggested implementation will decrement the count upon return from constructor (the automatic `shared_ptr` instance will be destructed). So if the compiler is not able to optimize to noop, you just pay the cost of two extra atomic operation for no gain and an added logical error that will backlash with a UB.

Regardless of the devised semantics, the constructor must increment the count. However, your proposed solution -after fixing the bug you've introduced- combines the implementation of both r-value and l-value versions of the constructor in a by-value constructor, discarding the mandatory atomic access optimization imposed by current implementation.